# Double integral in a polygon domain

Tags: integration, polygons, green-function, path-integral

I want to compute a integral of a polynomial $f(x, y)$ over a polygon domain $D$ of $n$ sides.

$$
I(f) = \int_{D} f(x, \ y) \ dx \ dy
$$

The vertex of this polygon are

$$\vec{p}_{i} = (x_i, \ y_i) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ i = 1, \ 2, \ \cdots , \ n$$

The main aproach is transform this integral over the domain in a integral over the boundary using Green's theorem.

$$
\int_{D} \left(\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\ dA = \oint_{C} P \ dx + Q \ dy
$$

Where the path $C$ is

$$
\partial D = C = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup \cdots \cup C_{n} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} C_{i}
$$

And $C_{i}$ is defined by the linear parametrization with $t \in \left[0, \ 1\right] $

$$
\vec{p}(t) = \left(1-t\right)\cdot \vec{p}_{i} + t \cdot \vec{p}_{i+1}
$$
$$
x(t) = \left(1-t\right) \cdot x_{i} + t \cdot x_{i+1}
$$
$$
y(t) = \left(1-t\right) \cdot y_{i} + t \cdot y_{i+1}
$$

And therefore the integral $I$ is just

$$
I = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \int_{C_i} P \ dx + Q \ dy = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} \left(P, \ Q\right) \cdot \dfrac{d\vec{p}}{dt} \ dt
$$

$$
\boxed{ I =
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \int_{0}^{1} \left(P, \ Q\right) \cdot \left(\vec{p}_{i+1}-\vec{p}_{i}\right) \ dt}
$$

To compute this integral, I can choose whatever I want for $P$ and $Q$ such that

$$
f(x, \ y) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} Q(x, \ y) - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} P(x, \ y)
$$

And then compute the sum.

**The question:**  Why the expression is not unique?

Like, if I choose a pair $(P_1, \ Q_1)$, I get a function $g_1(x_1, \ y_1, \ \cdots, \ x_{n}, \ y_{n})$.
But if I choose another pair $(P_2, \ Q_2)$, I get $g_2(x_1, \ y_1, \ \cdots, \ x_{n}, \ y_{n})$ with

$$
g_1 \ne g_2
$$

**Example:** In the video [Michael Penn - Overkill - The area of a rectangle](https://youtu.be/Y2cBpBLJlfU) we have $f(x, y) = 1$.

Then he chose $P = 0$ and $Q = x$ to get

$$
I(1) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \dfrac{(x_{i+1}+x_{i})(y_{i+1}-y_{i})}{2}
$$

But if I choose $P=-y$ and $Q = 0$ I get

$$
I(1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{(x_{i+1}-x_{i})(y_{i+1}+y_{i})}{2}
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Is it surprising for you that, say, in the one-dimensional case the antiderivative is not unique (one can add any constant) or what? Of course, in dimension $1$ the space of closed ($d\omega=0$) differential $0$-forms  is rather meager but in dimension $d\ge 2$ the corresponding space of $d-1$-forms is huge.

Comment: I looked more about it and I found that if I expand around $j$, the expressions are the same. So the total expression is always the same although the expression inside the sum is not the same. I will add an answer to explain that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, I got that

$$
I(1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{(x_{i+1}+x_{i})(y_{i+1}-y_{i})}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{(x_{i+1}-x_{i})(y_{i+1}+y_{i})}{2}
$$

And it's indeed correct. If I expand around $j$, I get that

$$
I(1) = \sum_{i=1}^{j-2} \square + x_{j}\left(y_{j+1}-y_{j-1}\right) + y_{j}\left(x_{j-1}-x_{j+1}\right)+ \sum_{i=j+1}^{n} \square
$$

To say that

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}} I(1) = y_{j+1} - y_{j-1}
$$
$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_{j}} I(1) = x_{j-1} - x_{j+1}
$$

For other polynomials $f$, it's harder to get a closed formula to that.